# Encode multiple label categorical variables with consideration of the frequency and standardization

Tags: classification, pandas, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I'm currently working on a dataset containing, among other features, multi-labeled categorical data per person for the last 3 years. I'm not sure how to handle this kind of categorical data where repetition occurs and is relevant.

Roughly simplified, I have a pandas dataframe with multiple features per id and one feature consisting of the multilabel category (e.g. products bought by a customer within the last years, where labels can be 5 different products):

```
    Var1  ...  products                        VarX 
0   val   ...  [prod1, prod2, prod1, prod3]    ...
1   val   ...  [prod5, prod1]                  ...
2   val   ...  [prod3] * 10                    ...
3   val   ...  [prod4, prod1, prod2]           ...  
4   val   ...  []                              ...
5   val   ...  [prod3, prod5, prod2]           ...
6   val   ...  [prod2, prod1, prod2, prod3]    ...
.   ...   ...  ...                             ...
```

Since MultilabelEncoder doesn't capture the frequency, I split the labels into separate columns counting all labels per id, looking like:

```
    Var1  ...  prod_1  prod_2  prod_3  prod_4  prod_5  VarX 
0   val   ...    2       1       1        0       0    ...
1   val   ...    1       0       0        0       1    ...
2   val   ...    0       0       10       0       0    ...
3   val   ...    1       1       0        1       0    ...
4   val   ...    0       0       0        0       0    ...
5   val   ...    0       1       1        0       1    ...
6   val   ...    1       2       1        0       0    ...
.   ...   ...   ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   ...
```

Now I'm stuck on how to proceed with the preparation of the dataset for ML training (the target variable is a binary value), with regards to standardization and rare label handling.

I thought about merging columns with a total count of non-zero occurences (not frequency) divided by the total dataset length lower than a certain threshold. But this outcome column can have a higher total count and frequency than the remaining category columns.

Furthermore I want to standardize the frequencies in every column, as products are not equivalent (4*"prod1" is not 4*"prod2"). But using a simple MinMaxScaler doesn't account for outliers in the respective columns (like the one customer buying 10 times "prod3").

Thanks for any help and hints!